# Writing contents of two list to two different sheets in the same excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel, list

I am working on couple of `C# list` which need to be written to an excel workbook into two different sheets `Sheet1 and Sheet2` but having no idea on how to deal with excel using interop I am using the following method

```
public void ExportListToExcel(List<String> listExport,string sheetName)
        {
 try
            {

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
                worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
                worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;

                for (int i = 1; i < listExport.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    //int count = 1;
                    worksheet.Cells[i, 1] = listExport[i - 1];
                    //count++;
                }
                string fileDestination = @"C:\Atlas Applications\AxiomParser\axiom.xls";
                if (File.Exists(fileDestination))
                {
                    File.Delete(fileDestination);
                }

                workbook.SaveAs(fileDestination, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                workbook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                Process.Start(fileDestination);
                app.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
```

ExportListToExcel(listMultiRowThreeWay,"Sheet1");
 ExportListToExcel(listMultiRowButterFly, "Sheet2");

I am calling the above method twice with two sheet names in the method but it give me an `invalid index error` when executing the method for the second time
 [image]

```
**Is there a better way to do it?**
```

Comment: what error are you getting .. you can't just call `app.Quit()` are you familiar with Disposing of ComObject when using InterOp...? please show how you are calling it twice as well as the exception / error message that you are getting

Comment: what line does it error out at ..? or what is the value of I when it errors I suspect that you're counter is off meaning you should start your for loop off with i = 0, or you need to do listExport.Count vs listExport.Count + 1 try that out first

Comment: worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;               Is this line required .. just a thought ...

Comment: this line looks confusing as well `worksheet.Cells[i, 1] = listExport[i - 1];`

Comment: can you show the using declaration at the top of the .cs file as to how you are using Microsoft.Interop.Excel..?

Comment: I am just calling it normally like ExportListToExcel(listMultiRowThreeWay,"Sheet1");
 ExportListToExcel(listMultiRowButterFly, "Sheet2");

Comment: try adding something like this at the end of the your try.. add a finally {} block and release the comobject 

 `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
 Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
 Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
            app = null;`